# How to remove "Empty String passed to getElementById()" warning with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: firefox, jquery-mobile

While using Firefox (23.0.1) and jQuery Mobile (1.3.2), I get the following warning from my code:  `Empty string passed to getElementById()`.  The message appears in the console (Tools > Web Developer > Web Console).   I would like to eliminate this warning.

I have seen a number of people ask similar questions, most notably: [Best way to locate source of Warning: Empty string passed to getElementById()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790435/best-way-to-locate-source-of-warning-empty-string-passed-to-getelementbyid)  The answers seems to fairly consistently point to the use of '#', implying the user is at fault.

I have tried to produce what I feel is the bare minimum of valid code, and I've found this warning is still exhibited.  I assume, from the other posts, that it is my code that is at fault.  Can anyone show me how to fix this issue?

As per other users' comments, this warning does not appear in Chrome (version 29.0.1547.57)

Thanks in advance!

**Minimum valid code that reproduces this issue:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="TestPage">

  <div data-role="content" id="TestContent">

    <p>This is a test</p>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: It produces the warning "Empty string passed to getElementById()" in Firefox's console.

Comment: where is the `getElementById()` called in this code?

Comment: getElementById() is called within jQuery Mobile's code (line 10827 of jquery.mobile-xxx-.js).  If you'd like to see this problem in action, have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/DFsYv/.  Note that the problem seems limited to jQuery Mobile 1.3.x.

Comment: Hey maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18863758/1091751) will clarify the warning you're getting. If you save the bare minimum code you posted and load it in a browser, try appending any hash (eg. #foo) to the end of the url and reloading, it will make the error go away.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's good insight.  I think the conclusion is that a quick test needs to be added to jQuery Mobile so that it does not call getElementById() with an empty string.  Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: I have the same issue and it seems to be caused by bootstrap (in mozilla). Adding #something did not help.

Comment: Also the page does not have any duplicate ids as is hinted in some other threads.

Comment: @Renra, I've pretty much given up trying to solve this one.  It has no impact except to consistently produce the (annoying) warning.  I suspect it would be best if a small modification was added to jQuery's code to get rid of the warning, but I've concluded it's really not worth stressing about.

Answer (score 21):

In my case it was caused because I forgot to specify a value for the 'for' attribute of a label:

**Missing id**

```
<label for="">Stuff:</label>
```

**fixed**

```
<label for="someID">Stuff:</label>
```

**EDIT: Removing the for attribute also prevents that warning**

```
<label>Stuff:</label>
```

Comment: Just came across the same exact scenario today and was able to correct thanks to this answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can also delete the `for` attribute and the warning will disappear.

Comment: this worked for me, but if i may, how does having `for` blank cause this warning?

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad I am not sure why either.

Comment: Suhaib its because the browser is searching for an item/element via Javascript, through the getElementById Api but no such element exist's.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in a deleted answer and in the comments, this was [a bug in Mobile jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7589) and it's now fixed. Compare the behavior of 1.3.2 vs 1.4.5 (the current version):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" /-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <!--script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script-->
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="TestPage">

  <div data-role="content" id="TestContent">

    <p>This is a test</p>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

After going through your jsfiddle I still didn't get where the the function document.getElementById() is being called. I used to also face this problem, but since you are using jquery-mobile its better to use $(#id) as selector just check whether this reference document.getElementById() or $('#id') is being called before the DOM is ready..

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, but as per my comment to Ryan, there are no selectors in use.  I've really concluded this warning should be considered a bug in jquery mobile.